# Javascript slideshow pause on mouseover, resume on mouseout

Tags: javascript

I am very new to coding and not been able to find a solution for this for weeks, most likely due to my lack of javascript understanding. I have a responsive image slider that is both auto and can be controlled with arrows.

I Have been attempting to get it to pause on mouseover (or hover) and resume on mouseout, but haven't quite resolved it. I've managed to get it to work on the first mouseover and mouseout actions with the code below, but if you mouseover again it does not pause; in fact, it completely ruins the timing and sequence.

It's been driving me mad and I'd appreciate any help. I'd also prefer to do this in Javascript specifically as I want to learn it and haven't begun JQuery yet, if that isn't too much trouble.

html:

```
<div id="container_main">
  <div class="container_slider" onMouseOver="pauseSlides()" onMouseOut="resumeSlides()">
    <div class="slides style">
      <div class="slide-number">1 / 3</div>
      <img title="carousel04" src="../images/practice/carousel04.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />
      <div class="slide-caption">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slides style">
      <div class="slide-number">2 / 3</div>
      <img title="carousel05" src="../images/practice/carousel05.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />
      <div class="slide-caption">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slides style">
      <div class="slide-number">3 / 3</div>
      <img title="carousel06" src="../images/practice/carousel06.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />
      <div class="slide-caption">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="arrows">
  <tr>
    <td class="left-arrow" title="previous"><img src="../images/icons/left-arrow.svg" width="20px" onClick="changeSlide(-1)" alt="" /></td>
    <td class="right-arrow" title="next"><img src="../images/icons/right-arrow.svg" width="20px" onClick="changeSlide(1)" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.container_slider {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1587px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'robotoregular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slides{
    display: none;
}

.style {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1800ms;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1800ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .5} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .5} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

.slide-caption{
    display: none;
    color:#000;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide-number{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'robotobold_italic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

table.arrows{
    width: 24%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.left-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.right-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

script:

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 0; //establishes slideIndex variable as equal to 0
  showSlides(); //???
  var slides;

  function pauseSlides() {
    clearTimeout(slideIndex);
  }

  function showSlides() { //establishes showSlides as a function
    var i; //establishes 'i' variable
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides"); //establishes 'slides' variable as equal to the class: "slides"
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
  }

  function resumeSlides() {
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
  }

  // Next/previous controls
  function changeSlide(position) {
    slideIndex += position;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    } else if (slideIndex < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  function currentSlide(index) {
    if (index > slides.length) {
      index = 1
    } else if (index < 1) {
      index = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      slides[index - 1].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You have `clearTimeout(slideIndex)`, which doesn't make much sense. `slideIndex` is the index of your slides, not the timeout you want to clear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `slideIndex` has NOTHING to do with the interval id that is active. The intervalID is the id given by setTimeout

```
intervalId = window.setTimeout( function() { })
```

and you use that to remove the interval

```
window.clearTimeout(intervalId)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. By incorporating this and setting my on mouseout action to the showSlides function i was able to get it stopping and starting, however, it is still behaving strangely. On mouseout the slider will immediately jump to the next slide or back to the beginning as if the timer is still running.

Comment: probably want mouseenter and mouseleave